# Конвертировать дату

Tags: java, android

Получаю данные **time**  - "Creation date of the item, in [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)."

Такого примера - 1479664016

Код в адаптере:

```
 viewHolder.date.setText(String.valueOf(myList.get(i).getTime()));
```

Как возможно правильно преобразовать в примерно такое: "MM dd, yyyy hh:mma"

Нашёл [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8034956/6387618), но затрудняюсь как и куда его правильно вставить.

Comment: Покажите приходящие данные и то как должно быть на выходе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете объект с помощью которого можно преобразовать unix timestamp в текстовую строку определенного формата:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
```

Преобразуете:

```
String stringDate = sdf.format(myList.get(i).getTime()*1000L);
```

Устанавливаете полученное значение:

```
viewHolder.date.setText(stringDate);
```

Вторую и третью строки можно объединить в одну.